# Why when trying to build my application to android phone the button Build And Run is disabled?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[image: can't build and run]

I wanted only build it first then run it from the phone but the button is disabled.

Is there an option to build it only first on the phone or it must be Build And Run?
And why the button is disabled?

I also get a message on the console:

Unauthorized device detected, Id: R5CT13313PL, please add debug authorization and reconnect.
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()

Comment: You havent clicked switch platform yet

Comment: The unity icon shows which platform is selected.  As @BugFinder stated, you need to actually switch the platform using the button.